# how to initialize in a text box as calendar with wordpress contact form 7 calendar plugin

Tags: wordpress, datepicker

I have installed and activate Contact form 7 calendar plugin in my wordpress website,But i don't khow the process to to add this plugin in my registration page Date Of Birth field..

Answer (score 0):

To use date field in contact for 7 please go with follows

1.Configure http://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-datepicker/ plugin it is an extension on contact form 7.

2.Activate it.

3.Create the date field as same like as other, from word-press dashboard contact form 7 plugin.

4.Insert contact form short-code to desired page where you want to display.It will automatically add date picker on date field.

Hope this one will help you.

Thanks